# Bike search in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

The goal of this coding problem is to create Html search input and bootstrap spinner achieve the design with html css and functionality with JS. When the page is opened make an Http request using Get method using the Fetch the url https://apis.ccbp.in/city-bikes?bike-name=
the children elements of the html container element with id search results should be dynamically created html container elements only.
Create HTML elements dynamically to set the data i.e.,bike name and city and add the newly created elements to the HTML container element with id search results.

The goal of this coding problem is to create Html input search and bootstrap spinner achieve the design with html css and functionality with JS. When the page is opened make an Http request using Get method.the children elements of the html container element with id search results should be dynamically created html container elements only.
Create HTML elements dynamically to set the data i.e.,bike name and city and add the newly created elements to the HTML container element with id search results.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). To get the best answers to your question we like to see that you've attempted to solve the problem yourself first using a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Here's a [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) you might find useful...

Answer (score 1):

The code includes an input field to search, a button to trigger the search, a spinner to prompt loading, and a container to display the search results. The JavaScript function `searchBikes` is responsible for making the HTTP request, handling the response, and dynamically creating the HTML element based on the received data.

```js
    function searchBikes() {
      const searchInput = document.getElementById('searchInput').value.trim();
      const searchResults = document.getElementById('search-results');
      const spinnerContainer = document.querySelector('.spinner-container');

      searchResults.innerHTML = '';

      spinnerContainer.style.display = 'block';

      fetch(`https://apis.ccbp.in/city-bikes?bike-name=${searchInput}`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
          spinnerContainer.style.display = 'none';

          data.forEach(bike => {
            const bikeContainer = document.createElement('div');
            bikeContainer.className = 'card mt-2';
            bikeContainer.innerHTML = `
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">${bike.city}</h5>
                <p class="card-text">${bike.id}</p>
                <p class="card-text">${bike.name}</p>
              </div>
            `;
            searchResults.appendChild(bikeContainer);
          });
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
          spinnerContainer.style.display = 'none';
        });
    }
```

```css
#search-results {
      margin-top: 20px;
    }

    .spinner-container {
      display: none;
    }

    .card-body {
      border: 1px solid #666;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      padding: 10px 20px;
    }

    .card-body h5 {
      margin: 0;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <h1>Bike Search</h1>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="searchInput">Search:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="searchInput" placeholder="Enter bike name">
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="searchBikes()">Search</button>

    <div class="spinner-container">
      <div class="spinner-border text-primary" role="status">
        <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="search-results" class="mt-4"></div>
  </div>
```